# How to mock AngularJS $resource with $promise.then in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I have a  a factory which uses Angular resource to make API call. I then created a function called getObjectById and use the factory to query for that object and then modify the object before returning.

**Service:**

```
return getObjectById: function(id) {
   return objectFactory.getById({ id: id }).$promise.then(function(response) {
      return modifyObject(response.object);
   });
}
```

I want to test that modifyObject() is working correctly but modifyObject is a private function.

So to test it i'm trying to mock object the response object factory is returning with a spy.

**Test:**

```
beforeEach(function() {
   inject(function(objectFactory, $q) {
      spyOn(objectFactory, 'getById').and.returnValue({ $promise: $q.when(readJSON('test/resources/object.json'))});
   });
});
```

But everytime I run the test I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined

If I can get any help on getting it to work that will be great. Even suggestion if i'm doing the layout wrong. Using latest Version Of Jasmine

Comment: The `.and.` syntax is since Jasmine 2.0, are you using a 2.* version?

Comment: Yes i'm using the most up-to-date version of Jasmine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very late answer, but I just ran into the same issue in an AngularJS / Angular hybrid app. We are using jasmine v1, but imported jasmine v2 typing. Which means the TypeScript would not compile with v1 syntax but would fail with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined`.

The jasmine version needs to match the typing:

`"karma-jasmine": "0.1"` means jasmine v1 and requires `"@types/jasmine": "^1.3.0"`

`"karma-jasmine": "0.3"` would be jasmine v2 and requires `"@types/jasmine": "2.8"`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing bracket

```
spyOn(objectFactory, 'getById').and.returnValue({ $promise: $q.when(readJSON('test/resources/object.json'))});
```